# Is the only possible multiplicative structure on a finite dimensional vector space that of a product ring of finite field extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, nilpotence

Let $K$ be a field and $R$ a commutative ring that's a finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

Do we necessarily have (as rings)
$$
R \cong \Pi_{i=1}^n F_i
$$
for some finite field extensions $F_i \supseteq K$, with the usual product ring multiplication? Is there a proof of this or a counter example?

I know that $R$ is a field if and only if $R$ is a domain, so to have this not be the case a ring would need "sufficient" zero-divisors.

I was thinking about other possible multiplicative structures, and thought of those direct sums of products after a bit ($K^n$ or direct sums of finite field extensions). Is it possible to have other structures with less "obvious" multiplication?

I was trying to come up with a few, but the role of the identity seems to be troubling me:

I tried constructing one on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where
$$
(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (a^2c^2,b^2d^2)
$$
or something with each component multiplying non-trivially on the others, but then if the identity is $(e,f)$, then it doesn't act trivially:
$$
(a,b) = (a,b) \cdot (e,f) = (a^2e^2,b^2f^2) \implies e^2=a^{-1}
$$

The additive group will be isomorphic to $K^n$ by definition, so I'm thinking $(1,\dots,1)$ might always somehow be an identity element, at least up to an automorphism of $K^n$ for instance maybe $\mathbb{F}_p$ could somehow multiply through an additive homomorphism:
$$
\phi : \ \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p \ : \ 1 \mapsto a
$$
then let
$$
b * c := \phi\bigg(\phi^{-1}(b)\phi^{-1}(c)\bigg)
$$
but then this is just an automorphism so it's still a field, so $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ with one component the usual multiplication, and one twisted (is this the right word?) by $\phi$, would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ with the usual ring structure.

Maybe some sort of intertwining, on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for instance
$$
(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac,bcd)
$$
(where here if $(a,b)$ is the identity it wouldn't work).

I'm not sure where to start on a proof of non-existence either... Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Such things can have nilpotent elements, e.g., $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$, as well as other Jordan-block structures.

Comment: "$R \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F_i$", without any other context, suggests that it's the product ring.  For reasons related to what you said, it does not cover all rings. But all finite dimensional $F$ algebras are, in essence, "funny multiplication on $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n F_i$". In fact, representing this multiplication using $n\times n$ matrices is the entire point of representation theory of algebras.  Good examples, I suppose, are defining the complex numbers as a product in $\mathbb R^2$ and the quaternions in $\mathbb R^4$ that way.

Comment: Note that on the other hand, the existence of nilpotent elements is the only obstruction: if $R$ is reduced, then it is semi-simple, in other words it is a finite direct product of field extensions. (Here the finite dimension is important.)

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{C}$ is not a product $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, since that has nilpotents.

Comment: @JairTaylor "nonzero idempotents," i think you mean.  Note also the user mentions "less obvious multiplications" which I think means they are open to considering something other than the product ring operation.

Comment: Sorry, yes. or, zero divisors.

Comment: Also I suppose $\mathbb{C}$ is still a field with an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry for the late reply, it's possible I mean the product ring yes. By the direct sum I was meaning the ring where each $F_i$ multiplies component-wise/'with itself and not the others', so I think that would that be the product ring then? Is it that the direct sum doesn't come with a  standard multiplication?

Comment: @George Yes, it does.   Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no: The ring $R$ can have nilpotent elements, but any direct sum $\bigoplus F_i$ of fields $F_i$ cannot. The simplest example, mentioned by paul garrett in the comments, is:

**Example** For any field $K$ and $n > 1$, take $$R := K[x] / \langle x^n \rangle$$ and denote the image of $x$ under the projection $\Bbb F[x] \to \Bbb F[x] / \langle x^n \rangle$ by $\alpha$. Then $\alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n - 1}$ are nilpotent.

If $K$ is finite, then $R$ can also have counts of zero divisors not achievable by any sum of fields. For example, if $K = \Bbb F_2$, $n = 2$, the ring $$R = \Bbb F_2[x] / \langle x^2 \rangle$$ has $1$ zero divisor ($x$), but the only sums of fields extending $\Bbb F_2$ of dimension $2$ over $\Bbb F_2$ are

- $\Bbb F_2 \oplus \Bbb F_2 \cong \Bbb F_2[x] / \langle x^2 + x \rangle$ (which has $2$, $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$), and
- $\Bbb F_4 \cong \Bbb F_2[x] / \langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ (which is itself a field and so has none). (See, e.g., [Classification of two dimensional algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210183/classification-of-two-dimensional-algebras) .)

Comment: When the user says _Is it possible to have other structures with less "obvious" multiplication?_ I think that means they're open to multiplication other than the product ring operation.

Comment: @rschwieb Which is what this answer provides, isn't it?

Comment: @imtrying46 I think it definitely does not. It takes for granted that the product ring operation is given, and then proceeds to give two examples with nilpotent elements to say "look it doesn't cover those."  If one is acknowledging that other operations are allowed, then you can describe any finite dimensional $F$ algebra as a number of copies of $F$ with strange multiplication.

Comment: @rschwieb The way I understand the question is as follows: is a $K$-algebra $R$ with $\dim_K R<\infty$ necessarily isomorphic to a finite product $\prod_i F_i$ with product multiplication, for some finite field extensions $F_i\supseteq K$? It seems to me that the way you understand the question is whether $R$ is isomorphic to some $\prod_i F_i$ with some arbitrary multiplication (say such that it is a $K$-algebra). But this would be trivial, as $f:R\cong K^{\oplus n}$ as $K$-vector spaces, so we could just define the multiplication on $K^{\oplus n}$ via $f$, i.e. $ab:=f(f^{-1}(a)f^{-1}(b))$.

Comment: @imtrying46 I don't know what else to say. In a comment i warned the OP that many people would interpret it as the former interpretation, and asked if he meant the latter interpretation.  I thought he might mean the latter interpretation because numerous parts of the post suggest so, and the former interpretation has a rather trivial answer.  Unfortunately the poster has not seemed to address my question directly. With the comment at the top of this thread, I only sought to point out that this solution may be overlooking the OP's intent.

Comment: Granted, the _title_ suggests the former interpretation somewhat, but who knows. Really it'd be nice if George commented.

Comment: @rschwieb My interpretation of the question was the same as imtrying46's, though I agree that the rest of their post leaves some doubt about whether that's definitely what they have in mind. What exactly would be o.p.'s question if one allowed an arbitrary multiplication structure on $\bigoplus F_i$ making it a ring? Either way, like you say, it would be helpful if they clarified their intent.

Comment: @rschwieb Ok now I get your point. I‘m pretty sure though that OP means the former interpretation. Him mentioning „non-obvious multiplication“ on the product comes from the following line of thought: he searches an example which isn’t a product of fields with product multiplication, so his attempt is to directly come up with another „non-obvious multiplication“. Without the intuition of eg $K[x]/(x^2)$ this is perhaps not so obvious, which is why he asked the question. I think :)

Comment: @imtrying46 I think I meant the first interpretation of your second comment, yes. Thanks to you both for the comments so that I could see the lack of clarity!